Using **kwargs with dataclass and YAMLWizard
How can I store additional kwargs in the kwargs attribute using YAMLWizard?
I have a dataclass and want to store any kwargs that aren't explicitly defined in the kwargs attribute. I can accomplish this with the code below.
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from inspect import signature
from typing import Any


@dataclass
class Data:
    x: str
    y: str
    kwargs: Any = field(default_factory=dict)

    @classmethod
    def from_kwargs(cls, **kwargs):
        # Fetch constructors signature
        cls_fields = {fld for fld in signature(cls).parameters}

        # Split kwargs into native ones and new ones
        native_args, new_args = {}, {}
        for name, value in kwargs.items():
            if name in cls_fields:
                native_args[name] = value
            else:
                new_args[name] = value

        # Return new class storing new kwargs into kwargs attribute
        return cls(**native_args, kwargs=new_args)

params = dict(x='time', y='temp', linecolor='blue', linewidth=10)
data = Data.from_kwargs(**params)
data

Data(x='time', y='temp', kwargs={'linecolor': 'blue', 'linewidth': 10})

Now I want to do the same thing, but I want to read the data from a YAML file instead using the dataclass-wizard library.
from dataclass_wizard import YAMLWizard


@dataclass
class Class1a(YAMLWizard):
    data: list[Data] = field(default_factory=list)

cls1a = Class1a.from_yaml("""
data:
  - x: x1
    y: y1
    linecolor: blue
  - x: x2
    y: y2
    linecolor: red
    linewidth: 2
""")

cls1a

Class1(data=[Data(x='x1', y='y1', kwargs={}), Data(x='x2', y='y2', kwargs={})])

I expected this result because I'm not using Data.from_kwargs() to create the object. I thought maybe I could use the classmethod in the default_factory, but that produces th same result as above.
@dataclass
class Class1b(YAMLWizard):
    data: list[Data] = field(default_factory=list[Data.from_kwargs])

cls1b = Class1b.from_yaml("""
data:
  - x: x1
    y: y1
    linecolor: blue
  - x: x2
    y: y2
    linecolor: red
    linewidth: 2
""")

cls1b

Class1b(data=[Data(x='x1', y='y1', kwargs={}), Data(x='x2', y='y2', kwargs={})])

Any ideas on using the classmethod for storing additional kwargs in the kwargs attribute using YAMLWizard?

If you do not provide a data argument it will default to what the default_factory was instructed to be. If you do provide a data argument, the default_factory is ignored. Essentially, default_factory is useless to your cause or at least in the sense of it having some form of control over how data is parsed.

The unsupported fields are omitted before they even reach your dataclass. The output of the below illustrates that linewidth and linecolor are not present in the __init__ method arguments.
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, fields
from dataclass_wizard import YAMLWizard


@dataclass
class Data:
    x: str
    y: str
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs)
        
        args = [*args, *(kwargs.values())]
        for f in fields(self):
            setattr(self, f.name, args.pop(0))

            
@dataclass
class Class1b(YAMLWizard):
    data: list[Data] = field(default_factory=list[Data])


cls1b = Class1b.from_yaml("""
data:
  - x: x1
    y: y1
    linecolor: blue
  - x: x2
    y: y2
    linecolor: red
    linewidth: 2
""")

output
{'x': 'x1', 'y': 'y1'}
{'x': 'x2', 'y': 'y2'}

the data indexes in the yaml source are representing a single entire thing. Your dataclass should represent a single entire thing that provides default values for optional fields.
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from dataclass_wizard import YAMLWizard


@dataclass
class CellStyle:
    x: str
    y: str
    linecolor:str = 'black'
    linewidth:int = 1


@dataclass
class Tabular(YAMLWizard):
    data: list[CellStyle]


cell_styles = Tabular.from_yaml("""
data:
  - x: x1
    y: y1
    linecolor: blue
  - x: x2
    y: y2
    linecolor: red
    linewidth: 2
""")

print(*cell_styles.data, sep='\n')


I could define the extra kwargs in the class, but the problem is that there are more than in the example I provide. As an example, any of these arguments could be supplied as additional kwargs. That's why I was trying to find a solution where I didn't have to define everything so I could just supply **data.kwargs to a downstream function. I could also just add a kwargs key and put them all there, but I was trying to avoid the extra nesting.

@Simon1 - I understand what you are trying to do, it's just a terrible idea. It also won't ever happen because, YAMLWizard "eats" all the vars that do not exist as fields in your dataclass, before it even instances your dataclass. This is evidenced in my first example where linecolor and linewidth don't even make it to the kwargs of the dataclass. Also, a dataclass is basically a typedef (maybe struct). Trying to define a type definition as you go and have multiple instances that exist differently negates the entire point of a typedef.
